# Converting selected JSON tags to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON like -

```
[
  {
    "key": "033298fd-f792-4343-b145-852e9cdb680a",
    "value": {
      "total": 15452,
      "history": {
        "2019-11-05T23:05:14.53878Z": {
          "challenge": "readrules",
          "increase": 1,
          "total": 1
        },
        "2019-11-05T23:17:48.849886Z": {
          "challenge": "looksthesame",
          "increase": 100,
          "total": 1601
        }
     },
  ...
  ...
  ...
  }

 .... 2nd 'key' ....
}
```

where every 'key' is followed by a 'value' which has `history`. This 'history' again has a 'key' which is the `timestamp` and a value that has challenge details `challenge`, `increase` and `total`. 
I want to convert this to a pandas dataframe that looks something like -

```
key                                              timestamp                   challenge       increase   total
033298fd-f792-4343-b145-852e9cdb680a    2019-11-05T23:05:14.53878Z      readrules          1         1 
033298fd-f792-4343-b145-852e9cdb680a    2019-11-05T23:17:48.84986Z      looksthesame      100       101
```

I tried to work with -

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(json)
```

but that just flattens out the whole json into different columns.

Comment: Your desired outcome is vastly truncated. Please edit it so people can understand what your goal is. Or describe better the column names/structure you want.

Comment: Pandas `json_normalize` will not magically give the structure you need.  You need to restructure your input json so that each element in an array represents a row i.e in your case `timestamp`

Comment: I agree with @FatihAkici. At the very least we need a proper description of the transformations on the data.

Comment: Editted. I hope it's more descriptive now!

Comment: Have you tried anything other than the `json_normalize()`?

Comment: No! Not very experienced with JSON to dataframe conversion..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose your data names `data`, try:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.io.json.json_normalize([
        {
            "key": d["key"], 
            "timestamp": t, 
            "challenge": v['challenge'], 
            "increase": v['increase'], 
            "total": v['increase']
        } 
        for t,v in d['value']['history'].items() 
    ]) 
    for d in data
])
```

Comment: It's nested list comprehension. For each item `d` in `data` and `t`,`v` in each `d` you extract only the information you need in the dataframe.

Comment: @thushv89  gives the interpretation.